# How to print all the elements of a 2d array in python with a different number of rows than columns?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, range, 2d

I have a 2d array in python. I initialized it like this:

```
rows = 5
cols = 5
array = [[None for _ in range(rows)] for _ in range(cols)]
```

I want to add elements to each spot in the array. I did it like this:

```
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        array[i][j] = " 0 "
```

I also have a function that prints the array. It looks like this:

```
def printGrid():
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            print(array[i][j], end='')
        print("")
```

When the number of columns matches the number of rows it works and the output looks something like this:

[image]

The problem is when the number of cols is different than the number of rows I get this error (for example, if rows=5 and cols=4):

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can replace you function with single expression `print("\n".join((" ".join("0" * cols),) * rows))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list is initialized incorrectly.

It should be like:

```
array = [[None for _ in range(cols)] for _ in range(rows)]
```

which means create `rows` number of list where each `row` list has `cols` elements.

Comment: Just tried that. Fixed it. Cols are horizontal and rows are vertical, so I assumed it would be rows then columns. Weird. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Awesome @btror. please consider accepting the answer to mark the question as resolved.

Comment: You can use `[None] * cols` instead of inner list comp

Comment: It won't let me accept the answer for another 5 minutes, but I definitely will.

Answer (score 2):

When initializing an array, the inner array specifies the columns and the outer specifies the rows, like so:
`array = [[None for x in range(cols)] for y in range(rows)]`

Complete Code:

```
rows = 7
cols = 6
array = [[None for x in range(cols)] for y in range(rows)]

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        array[i][j] = " 0 "

for k in range(rows):
    for l in range(cols):
        print(array[k][l], end='')
    print("")
```